# Connection error to Redshift in Spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am building a spark project using scala in Intellij. I have added the following dependencies:

```
spark-redshift_2.10-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT
RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.7.1007
httpcore-4.4.3
httpclient-4.5.1 
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.23-SNAPSHOT
aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.23-SNAPSHOT
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils
```

when running

```
val df = sqlContext.read.foramat("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
.option("url", "jdbc:redshift://AWS_SERVER:5439/warehouse?user=USER&password=PWD")
.option("dbtable", "fact_time")
.option("tempdir", "s3n://bucket/path")
.load()

df.show()
```

Comment: I was thinking about your problem. A solution would be to put your dependency on s3, copy them on cluster startup, install on your cluster and then run your application.

Answer (score 2):

I helped to debug this issue over at the [`spark-redshift` issues page](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/103). The problem ultimately [turned out](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/103#issuecomment-145621331) to be caused by missing transitive dependencies which caused ClassNotFoundExceptions during static initialization of the `com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils` class, leading to the error reported here. The fix was to add those missing dependencies to the IntelliJ project.